# How to make RecyclerView Item Divider responsive to different screens?

Tags: java, android, responsive-design, responsive

### ***Responsiveness Issue***

I am using a class called DividerItemDecoration, it's used to make divisions between the recyclerview items, I implement left and right margins using glue code which i think will not work as expected with other devices such as tablets as an example or other devices with taller screens
Here is my code:

```
public class DividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[]{
        android.R.attr.listDivider
};

public static final int HORIZONTAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL;

public static final int VERTICAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL;

private Drawable mDivider;

private int mOrientation;

public DividerItemDecoration(Context context, int orientation) {
    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ATTRS);
    mDivider = a.getDrawable(0);
    a.recycle();
    setOrientation(orientation);
    mDivider.setColorFilter( 0xC1D0D7, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
}

public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
    if (orientation != HORIZONTAL_LIST && orientation != VERTICAL_LIST) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid orientation");
    }
    mOrientation = orientation;
}

@Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
        drawVertical(c, parent);
    } else {
        drawHorizontal(c, parent);
    }
}

public void drawVertical(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    final int leftMargin=100;
    final int rightMargin=250;
    final int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    final int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount-1; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                .getLayoutParams();
        final int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
        final int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDivider.setBounds(left+leftMargin, top, right-rightMargin, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}

public void drawHorizontal(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    final int top = parent.getPaddingTop();
    final int bottom = parent.getHeight() - parent.getPaddingBottom();

    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                .getLayoutParams();
        final int left = child.getRight() + params.rightMargin;
        final int right = left + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight() +params.leftMargin;
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
        outRect.set(0, 0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight());
    } else {
        outRect.set(0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have different dimension values for padding in different layout folders similar to the layouts.

For example,

Under `res/values/` folder:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="divider_padding">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Under `res/values-sw600dp/` folder:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="divider_padding">20dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And then reference it at runtime using,

```
int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.divider_padding);
```

You will receive 16dp in phones, and 20dp in tablets with minimum 600dp width.

Comment: there's an error with getResources() , when I import it, it tells me that it's not public in picasso package

Comment: What error? And where are you calling that getResources() method?

Comment: inside drawVertical method

Comment: com.square.picasso.utils is not public in com.square.picasso , it cannot be accessed from an outside package

Comment: Call this from the constructor and save the value in a field. call using `context`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: If it's working, would you please mark the answer as correct.